# Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

It seems the webdriver is not working properly.
What do you think is happening with the following message below?

File "C:\Users\aross\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\instapy\unfollow_util.py", line 1013, in get_given_user_followers
    person_list, simulated_list = get_users_through_dialog_with_graphql(
  File "C:\Users\aross\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\instapy\unfollow_util.py", line 767, in get_users_through_dialog_with_graphql
    browser.get("view-source:{}".format(url))
  File "C:\Users\aross\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Users\aross\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\aross\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: Timeout loading page after 300000ms